# how to reply to a tweet using linqtotwitter

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I'm trying to reply to a tweet using this method:

```
twitterCtx.ReplyAsync(statusid, "test");
```

However, it just posts a new tweet on my page. I can reply to my own tweet using the above code but it does not work for other people's tweet.

How can I reply to a tweet using linqtotweet? Also the value of InReplyToStatusID is 0 always!!

Comment: Did you try Joe Mayo's suggestion on Twitter (see: https://twitter.com/JoeMayo/status/1000545992507207681) If so, did it work?

Comment: @Japp Yeah that does the job thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `ReplyAsync`, you need to prefix the message with a mention of the user the reply is for, like this:

```
twitterCtx.ReplyAsync(statusid, "@UserName test");
```